# An identity for the Fibonacci number $F_{n^2}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, fibonacci-numbers

I was manipulating Fibonacci numbers defined by :

- $F_0=0$ and $F_1=1$
- $ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$  $F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n$

Until I obtain this equation (which I proved) $\forall n\in \mathbb{N^*}$:

$F_{n^2}=\sum_{k=0}^n C_n^kF_{n-k}F_{n-1}^{k}F_n^{n-k}$

with $C_n^k=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

**Questions :** Is there a similar formula for the numbers $F_{n^3},\cdots,F_{n^p}$ ? (I'm just curious)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you please add the work that you've done on the question?  If this is homework, please read [How to ask a homework question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/23353) on meta

Comment: This is not a homework , I'm just curious about this numbers, I want to have a formula $F_{n^3}$ , Is there one!

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Other_identities) mentions the identity $$F_{kn+c} = \sum_{i=0}^k {k\choose i} F_{c-i} F_n^i F_{n+1}^{k-i}$$ which, if you take $c=0$ and $k=n$, yields an identity almost the same as yours: $$F_{n^2} = \sum_{i=0}^n {n\choose i} (-1)^iF_i F_n^i F_{n+1}^{n-i}.$$ But I am not interested in performing the toilsome calculations that would be required to change this to your form.

Comment: In fact , if we take $k=c=n$ and replace $n$ by $n-1$ we will get my identity, this is an answer for the first question what about the second one I'm just looking if there is an identity, i don't need any proof, thanks.

Comment: Take $k=n^2$ and $c=0$ in MJD's comment you get an identity for $F_{n^3}$

Comment: Ok, this is one suggestion, but it's not beautiful because there is a $C_{n^2}^k$ . If I understand there is no a well known identity.